# Durandal : ViewModel does not work in a common view

Tags: durandal

I'm trying to create a common area for my navigation/menus (vertical) in my shell page. This shell's menu area will then be updated by new set of menus on every page transition. heres inside my shell.js

```
define(function (require) {
var router = require('durandal/plugins/router');
var Menu = function (name, children) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.children = ko.observableArray(children);
}

var Menus = ko.observableArray([]);

function GetDSRList() {
    router.navigateTo('#/reports/list2');
}

function activate() {


    router.mapNav('reports/index', 'viewmodels/reports/index', 'Reports');
    router.mapNav('reports/list', 'viewmodels/reports/list', 'List');
    router.mapNav('reports/list2', 'viewmodels/reports/list2', 'List2');
    router.mapNav('home/menu', 'viewmodels/home/menu', 'Main');
    return router.activate('home/menu');
}

function viewAttached() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#panelbar").kendoPanelBar({
            expandMode: "single"
        }),

        $("#splitter").kendoSplitter({
            panes: [
                    { collapsible: false, resizable: false, size: "20%" },
                    { collapsible: false }
                   ]
        });
    });
}

function token() {
    return $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();
}

var shell = {
    router: router,
    activate: activate,
    viewAttached: viewAttached,
    GetDSRList: GetDSRList,
    Menus: Menus,
    token: token,
    Menu: Menu
}

return shell;
```

And for the View (shell.html)

```
<div style="height:100%;">
    <div class="loader" data-bind="css: { active: router.isNavigating }">

    </div>    

    <div id="splitter" style="border:0;height:100%">

            <div class="nav-panel-section">
                <ul id="panelbar">

                   <li data-bind="foreach : Menus">
                        <span class="k-link k-header" data-bind="text: name">
                             <span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s k-panelbar-expand"></span>
                        </span>
                            <ul data-bind="foreach: children">
                                <li>
                                    <span class="k-link" data-bind="text: $data,click:this.GetDSRList"></span>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>


                </ul>
            </div>


            <a href="#/reports/list2">Log off</a>
            <div id ="partialContent">

                    <div class="container-fluid page-host">
                        <!--ko compose: { 
                            model: router.activeItem, //wiring the router
                            afterCompose: router.afterCompose, //wiring the router        
                            cacheViews:true //telling composition to keep views in the dom, and reuse them (only a good idea with singleton view models)
                        }--><!--/ko-->

                         <form method="post" action="Account/LogOff" id="logoutForm" >
                            <input type="hidden" name="__RequestVerificationToken" data-bind="value:token"/>
                        </form>
                    </div>

            </div>
    </div>        
</div>
```

Then going to the url '#/reports/list2' i have this viewmodel (list2.js) :

```
define(function (require) {

var shell = require('viewmodels/home/shell')


function activate() {
    shell.Menus = [];
    shell.Menus = [
                new shell.Menu("Menu3", ["A", "B", "C"]),
                new shell.Menu("Menu5", ["A", "B", "C"])
            ];
}

var list2 = {
    activate : activate
}

return list2;

});
```

But the shell's menu UI does not change unless you refresh the entire page. Am I missing something here? Thnx

Comment: I think you need to edit your question as the html is not visible at present and that's going to be useful in solving this.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you create an observableArray and then wipe it out on the new view model load.  You need to use the setter function for your observableArray to maintain it's connection to the DOM (please don't correct my grammar on that one, trying to KISS!!)

```
function activate() {
    shell.Menus = ([]);
    shell.Menus = ([
                new shell.Menu("Menu3", ["A", "B", "C"]),
                new shell.Menu("Menu5", ["A", "B", "C"])
            ]);
}
```

Simply adding the parans should fix your issue.  When you are clearing use the parans, when you are setting use the parans.

Comment: the problem is still the same even with parans, but if i force to refresh the page these new values of menus appears and that is not how the KO works, for some reason it can't repaint my shell page, by the way I am using asp.net mvc 4 and razor for rendering the page, could it be the reason?

Comment: No it should not be at all.  Where are you setting the initial values of menus?  I dint see it in your shell view model after instantiation.

Comment: Menus will always be empty in shell at index page as required , the only time it will be populated is when the user selected different URLs, that's the reason I put the menus inside the shell view model so I can have a common visible view for entire application like a master page.